# how to display values from buffer

Tags: c++, c, embedded, contiki

I am trying to display the values in a buffer.

A client node sends its temperature and data length as payload in the buffer to the server. The server is then supposed to receive and display the same values put in.

I have the following:

```
    handler(void)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN);//set payload
        if(uip_newdata()) { //if new data is received from client
            leds_on(LEDS_RED);
            len = uip_datalen();
            memcpy(buf, uip_appdata, len); 
            printf("buffer = %s", buf);
            PRINTF("%u\n\r bytes from [", len);
            PRINT6ADDR(&UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
            PRINTF("]:%u\n\r", UIP_HTONS(UIP_UDP_BUF->srcport));        
        }
```

I have a feeling that the memcpy line or the "printf" line is wrong because the other printf work.

Please help
Json

Comment: What is your question? What is the error? A feeling?

Comment: Are `PRINTF` and `printf` different functions or a typo?

Comment: Do you expect `uip_appdata` to contain ASCII characters or some kind of binary data? (e.g. if the first byte was `'\0'`, `printf()` wouldn't print anything

Comment: Variable declarations and type information for the variables in use are essentially to know for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of data you would like to extract from the buffer, but if it contains a '\0' at the beginning, the printf("buffer = %s", buf); will not show any data.

When I want to debug buffer and I know the output does not contain ASCII characters, I use the following example:

```
char buf[MAX_BUF_LEN];

do_fill_buffer_stuff(buf);
// Print the output of the buffer as Hexadecimal values:
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUF_LEN; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", buf[i] & 0xff);
}
printf("\n");
```

This will give you a series of hexadecimal values present in your buffer.

Comment: First of all, the Data type being passed in the buffer is a standard integer. I have only decided to send the decimal part of the temperature value just to test the code (which should be fairly simple). Eventually it is supposed to send multiple values in one packet to the server. Secondly, This is the first time i am ever hearing of a difference between PRINTF and printf. According to lib code, the only difference is that one requires the "stdio.h" file - thats all. I am currently integrating Jan Jaap's code into mine and ill post back with results. thank you

Comment: I integrated the code into mine and the server output is messy. With the loop it prints out the hex of the first value of the buffer the prints out "00" for the rest. I editted the code to :        
   //for ( i = 0; i < MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN; i++)
   //{
       printf(">> %s ", buf[0]);
   //}
  //PRINTF("buffer = %s", buf);

But this also doesnt print out any correct values.

Comment: Thank you Jan Jaap.
I worked with your code I can correctly display the value i want held by a variable. The only change I made was the parameters passed in the loop. It was set to MMAXBUFLEN but that variable only held a constant figure of 120 (bytes) but what it was supposed to loop through was the length 'len' of the packet received. 
Thanks a lot